# Use dynamic reconfiguration to set the parameter value in ROS

Tags: ros

I am new to ROS and i want to use Dynamic reconfiguration technique to set a parameter (`rectangle_height`).

Through internet i came across with the following method but its not working.

**Problem:** when i run `rqt_reconfigure`, in that my node (visual_analysis) is not visual so i can't change the parameter.

-In my **Includes**, i have included the following:

```
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/DoubleParameter.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Reconfigure.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Config.h>
```

-In my **`main()`** where my variable is declared, i have written the following:

```
int main( )
{
    double rectangle_height;

    ///////////////////Dynamic Reconfig
    dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureRequest srv_req;
    dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureResponse srv_resp;
    dynamic_reconfigure::DoubleParameter double_param;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf;   

    //Entering values using Dynamic Reconfig
    double_param.name = "kurtana_pitch_joint";
    double_param.value = rectangle_height;
    conf.doubles.push_back(double_param);

    srv_req.config = conf;
    ros::service::call("/visual_analysis/set_parameters", srv_req, srv_resp);


    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the following steps to have the dynamic Reconfig working:

- Make a `cfg` folder and create a .cfg file where you can declare the parameters you want to change using dynamic reconfig.
- Make changes in your `CMakeList.txt` and `MakeFile` to adapt them for dynamic reconfig
- Make a `dynamicReconfigCallBack()` in which you can receive/set the changed parameters.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode%28cpp%29) for further detials.